# Split text into 2 colors

Tags: c#, .net, text, gdi+

I am making a custom progress bar in C#, and I want to show the percent on top of the bar. I need it so that when the bar reaches the text, it changes color. Take for example the image I made below:

[image]

Pretend that the orange rectangle on the left is the progress bar, and the black rectangle is blank space.

Is there anyway I can recreate this using GDI?

Thanks in advance,
Pat

Comment: you can apply effect to the image so it seems a nice progress bar :), see [here](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/08/28/display-unique-progress-bars-in-c.aspx) how to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by overriding paint on the control of your choice,

First draw the Black background and orange text

```
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, panel1.ClientRectangle);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("StackOverflow", Font, Brushes.Orange, panel1.ClientRectangle);
```

Then Draw the overlay and clip to the size of the progress value

```
    var clipRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (panel1.Width / 100) * _progress, panel1.Height);
    e.Graphics.SetClip(clipRect);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, clipRect);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("StackOverflow", Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
```

This is a working example using `Panel` as the control to override paint on (Just add a panel to a Form)

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer _progresstimer = new Timer();
    private int _progress = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);
        _progresstimer.Interval = 250;
        _progresstimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
         {
             if (_progress < 100)
             {
                 _progress++;
                 panel1.Invalidate();
                 return;
             }
             _progress = 0;
             panel1.Invalidate();
         };
        _progresstimer.Start();
    }



    void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, panel1.ClientRectangle);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("StackOverflow", Font, Brushes.Orange, panel1.ClientRectangle);

        var clipRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (panel1.Width / 100) * _progress, panel1.Height);
        e.Graphics.SetClip(clipRect);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, clipRect);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("StackOverflow", Font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

You will want to set `DoubleBuffering` etc as this will flicker without, but this should be a good starting example.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Pat Welcome to [so]. There's a holo tickbox next to each answer. Marking the correct answer gives you a couple of points and lets everyone know your problem is resolved and saves people from further troubleshooting. Good luck!